# How to upload Cloudinary image only on successful CRUD operations in Node.js using Multer?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, multer, cloudinary

I have created a CRUD project as a student, where I am storing profile images on Cloudinary using Multer. I want the profile image to be uploaded to Cloudinary only when a student's data is successfully created or updated. Below are my controller functions for creating and updating a student:-

create function -

```
async function addNewStudent(req, res) {
     try {
     const { student_roll, student_name, student_email } = req.body;

    const existingStudentID = await Students.findOne({ student_roll });
    if (existingStudentID) {
        return res.status(400).json({ status: 400, message: `Student RollNo. '${student_roll}' already exists in the database.` });
    }

    const existingStudentEmail = await Students.findOne({ student_email });
    if (existingStudentEmail) {
        return res.status(400).json({ status: 400, message: `Student email '${student_email}' already exists in the database.` });
    }

    const result = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.file.path, { resource_type: 'image' });
    const newStudent = await Students.create({
        student_roll,
        student_name,
        student_email,
        profile_image: {
            public_id: result.public_id,
            secure_url: result.secure_url
        }
    });

    return actionCompleteResponse({ res, data: newStudent });
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return sendError({ res, error });
}}
```

update function -

```
async function updateStudent(req, res) {
         try {
         const updates = req.body;

    if (!ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id)) {
        throw 'NOT_VALID_DOCUMENT_ID';
    }

    const existingStudentID = await Students.findOne({ student_roll: updates.student_roll });
    if (existingStudentID) {
        return res.status(400).json({ status: 400, message: `Student roll no. '${updates.student_roll}' already exists in the database.` });
    }

    const existingStudentName = await Students.findOne({ student_name: updates.student_name });
    if (existingStudentName) {
        return res.status(400).json({ status: 400, message: `Student name '${updates.student_name}' already exists in the database.` });
    }

    const existingStudentEmail = await Students.findOne({ student_email: updates.student_email });
    if (existingStudentEmail) {
        return res.status(400).json({ status: 400, message: `Student email '${updates.student_email}' already exists in the database.` });
    }

    if (req.file) {
        const existingStudentImage = await Students.findOne({ _id: new ObjectId(req.params.id) });
        const imageID = existingStudentImage.profile_image.public_id;

        if (existingStudentImage.profile_image && imageID) {
            const deletePreviousImage = await cloudinary.uploader.destroy(imageID);
        }

        const newImage = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.file.path);
        updates.profile_image = {
            public_id: newImage.public_id,
            secure_url: newImage.secure_url
        };
    }

    const updatedStudent = await Students.updateOne({ _id: new ObjectId(req.params.id) }, { $set: updates });
    return actionCompleteResponse({ res, data: updates });
} catch (error) {
    return sendError({ res, error });
}
```

How can I ensure that the profile image is uploaded to Cloudinary only when a student's data is successfully created or updated ?

Comment: I think it's best create your own unique fileName and then create/update entity first with that file name, you can then do the upload and pass on the unique image name to cloudinary, https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/202520762-Uploading-assets-and-keeping-their-original-filenames

Comment: You should perform the image upload within the success block of the database operation